# brace-or-equal initialization vs constructor delegation

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

Perhaps my title might translate to "apples vs oranges", but I'm not quite sure so I'd like the SO community's help understanding some best practices.

Suppose I have the two examples.

**brace-or-equal initialization**

```
class foo
{
public:
  foo() {}
  foo(int a) : m_a(a) {}
  foo(int a, int b) : m_a(a), m_b(b) {}
  foo(int a, int b, int c) : m_a(a), m_b(b), m_c(c) {}

private:
  int m_a = 1;
  int m_b = 2;
  int m_c = 3;
};
```

**constructor delegation**

```
class foo
{
public:
  foo() : m_a(1), m_b(2), m_c(3) {}
  foo(int a) : foo() { m_a = a; }
  foo(int a, int b) : foo() { m_a = a; m_b = b; }
  foo(int a, int b, int c) : foo() { m_a = a; m_b = b; m_c = c; }

private:
  int m_a;
  int m_b;
  int m_c;
};
```

I feel like the first is better because it results in no double-initialization of variables. In the 2nd example, the last overload of foo's constructor is the worst because each member variable is initialized twice.

Which is the preferred method here? And assuming the former is preferred, when are delegated constructors useful?

Comment: Well, for your class I would have gone with `foo(int a = 1, int b = 2, int c = 3) : m_a(a), m_b(b), m_c(c) {}`

Comment: You are doing it wrong. It should be `foo() : foo(1,2,3)`

Comment: @T.C. I realize there are multiple other solutions compared to what is listed here, but my question is focused on only these 2 please.

Comment: Make `foo()` call `foo(int, int, int)`, not the other way around.

Comment: What if a constructor with four args is then added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to delegate from the constructor that takes fewer arguments to the constructor that takes the most, giving default values for the extra parameters:

```
foo( int a, int b, int c ) : m_a(a), m_b(b), m_c(c) {}
foo( int a, int b ) : foo( a, b, 3 ) {}
foo( int a ) : foo( a, 2, 3 ) {}
foo() : foo( 1, 2, 3 ) {}
```

Comment: This is a correct answer, however I failed to communicate my question properly. However I'm accepting this to avoid confusion. I'll think of a better way to ask my question later. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Like [clcto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26240157/2721883) pointed out, you should do delegation differently.

In reality we can do a little better (**With your given example!!!**) using default param values:

```
class foo
{
public:
  // no longer need all your other constructors
  foo(int a=1, int b=2, int c=3) : m_a(a),m_b(b),m_c(c){}

private:
  int m_a;
  int m_b;
  int m_c;
};
```

Your actual code may be different; i.e. you want to sometimes initialize `b` and not `a` or `c`, so you could instead use one of the other answers posted.

Comment: I think my example is *too* contrived. I've completely failed to make my point. My real example is more complicated. The default constructor does a lot more and basically it is being called to perform initialization of everything to a default state and then the constructor *doing* the delegation overwrites those default constructed values as needed.